# Can I open a new window and populate it with a string variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am having a bit of a battle with something that seems simple. I have a [javascript] string that has DOM elements in it and would like to open a new window (window.open()?) and use the string the populate the new window. i.e. have the browser take the string and convert it into HTML on the fly. Is this possible?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Yes it's possible...

```
var wnd = window.open("about:blank", "", "_blank");
wnd.document.write(html);
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: @JackFranzen I just tried it in the console and it still works fine.

Comment: I'm trying to instantiate a blank page in a new tab with a pre-populated script which waits for the blank page in the new tab to finish being instantiated and then displays an alert on the blank page in the new tab saying something like 'success'. Everything I've tried so far either displays the alert in the current tab, instantiating the blank page in a new tab only after addressing the alert -or else the blank page in the new tab and the alert are instantiated/displayed simultaneously, with the alert still appearing only outside of the blank page in the new tab.

Comment: @Musixauce3000 Start a new question and post your code if you need help with that.

Comment: Works in chrome, ff and ie12

Comment: Note that browsers have locked down `window.open` _a lot_ since 2013, and the better approach these days is to to use a link element with an appropriate data-uri (see [below](/a/55249864/740553))

Answer (score 7):

### HTML

Archer's answer is a good one, but you can do this in a one liner if you wish:

```
window.open("data:text/html;charset=utf-8,"+html, "", "_blank")
```

---

### Opening XML?

```
window.open("data:text/xml;charset=utf-8,"+xml, "", "_blank")
```

With XML, make sure you string begins with `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` and has a root element. If it doesn't, you can easily add it:

```
window.open('data:text/xml;charset=utf-8,<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><RootTag>'+xml+'</RootTag>', "", "_blank")
```

Comment: Your second example is invalid. You tried to nest double quotes.

Comment: First example in chrome window is open and close immidiatly. :(

Comment: I think you should mention the term `Data URI` here, you are opening a Data URI

Answer (score 6):

If you need in new tab you can use this.

```js
const win = window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
win.document.write('<h1>test</h1>');
win.focus();
```

Answer (score 5):

Archer's answer is the best way. But you need to close the document to run the scripts inside the "htmlString".

```
 var wnd = window.open("about:blank", "");
        wnd.document.write(htmlString);
        wnd.document.close();
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that while `window.open` was a good solution in 2013, at this point in time that is no longer the case, and `window.open` is not the right answer here anymore; it has become blocked-by-default by almost every browser due to years of abuse by ads, and is frowned upon as a legacy mechanism that completely bypasses the browser history when it *does* work.

Instead, build a link anchor element, assign its content as a data-uri, give it a `target="_blank"` so that it'll open in a new tab, and then trigger a `click()` on it so that it opens that content as a normal webpage with a normal entry in the browser's history:

```
function openAsPageInNewTab(pageContent) {
  let encoded = encodeURIComponent(pageContent); 
  let a = document.createElement(`a`);
  a.target = `_blank`;
  a.href = `data:text/html;charset=utf-8,${encoded}`;
  a.style.display = `none`;
  document.body.appendChild(a); // We need to do this,
  a.click();                    // so that we can do this,
  document.body.removeChild(a); // after which we do this.
}
```

You might of course still get a popup warning, because it should, but at least you're now doing things in a way that respects users and browsers, unlike the legacy `window.open` approach.

Comment: Sure.  Maybe clarify the "not right" with something more meaningful, like "superseded", for example.

Comment: I stumbled upon this answer from DDG. It is a great technique.

Comment: This data-uri technique no longer works in browsers that block top-frame navigation, like Chrome and Edge.

Comment: Indeed, the vastly superior solution these days is to open a real page (using the same `<a>` click approach, not window.open) that has no `<body>` content, and just enough JS to accept postMessage events from your original page, as well as just enough JS that lets it update its own DOM when the original page sends it the content it needs to show.