# Open new window in IE with custom html content

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I want to open a pop up window IE with custom html content. Using the answer provided on page  [Can I open a new window and populate it with a string variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493027/can-i-open-a-new-window-and-populate-it-with-a-string-variable)

I have used the following javascript snippet:

```
    var wnd = window.open("about:blank", "", "");
    wnd.document.write(htmlContent);
    wnd.document.close();
```

This code opens the content in a new tab instead of a pop up windows, so I used the extra parameter _blank as follows:

```
    var wnd = window.open("about:blank", "", "_blank");
    wnd.document.write(htmlContent);
    wnd.document.close();
```

Now, a popup opens with my content but it has no scroll bar, is not resizable and has no menu due to which printing is not possible. One approach I have already tried is using the windowfeatures parameter as follows:

```
  var strWindowFeatures = 
   "menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
    var wnd = window.open("about:blank", strWindowFeatures, "_blank");
    wnd.document.write(htmlContent);
    wnd.document.close();
```

But using this parameter has no effect on resulting popup. Additionally, in Chrome, the pop up has no content. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I kept on trying myself and using the window.open documentation on MDN Website

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open

I found the following solution:

```
  var wnd = window.open("about:blank", "", 
 "menubar,resizable,scrollbars,status");
  wnd.document.write(htmlContent);
  wnd.document.close();
```

I have tested this code in IE 11 and the popup window has the html content, is scrollable and resizable and the IE menu can be accessed by pressing Alt key. 
***IMPORTANT*** This code does not work in Chrome and a workable solution for Chrome is:

```
 window.open("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," +
                htmlContent, "", "_blank");
```

I took this solution from

[Can I open a new window and populate it with a string variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17493027/can-i-open-a-new-window-and-populate-it-with-a-string-variable)