# New page opens instead new window

Tags: javascript, html, kiosk, kiosk-mode

I have code that works in IE browser, issue with window.open().
In IE, it opens new window even IE is FULL SCREEN MODE OR NORMAL MODE.
In Edge it opens new window when Edge is in NORMAL MODE, but and it is redirect on main page when Edge is **in FULL SCREEN MODE that's why I loosing main screen**.
For full screen mode I have used below link in edge short cut properties.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --kiosk C:\Users\SoftwareUser\Desktop\Test.html  --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen
Note:- Full Screen mode, my project requirement.

Test.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>The Window Object</h1>
<h2>The open() Method</h2>

<p>Click the button to open a new browser window.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
 var newWindow = window.open("https://www.google.com/",'OrangeHRM','_blank','fullscreen=NO, status=no, location=no, resizable=no');
    return;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

please any one help me to overcome this and suggest any alternative or help for this.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44332326/7644018) help?

Comment: HI Paul, By mistake JAVA was added now corrected. and thanks for your replay but sorry to say your suggested code also not working,  same redirecting (open new window) on same screen.